# Optional Group python Rgx

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
string = 'Alabama[edit]'
a = re.search(r'(\w+)(?:\(([\w+\s*]+)\))(\[.*\])',string).group(2)
```

I have made the () in the optional group, but the result still returned None.
what I want to achieve is that there are two different types of string:

1.Alabama[edit]
2.Alabama (some text)[edit]

I want to abstract either none , if there is no parenthesis or the string in the 
parenthesis.

And also I am not sure why this doesn't work for the optional Group I mean if there is on parenthesis , this expression should be ignored and capture the rest group which are captured right?

```
(?:\(([\w+\s*]+)\))
```

thanks!
Erik

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Please take your time and say what you are trying to achieve, what is your expected result vs the actual. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @K.Kirsz thanks you ,I have made edition for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
a = re.search('(\w+)(\([\w+\s*]+\))?(\[.*\])',string).groups()
print(a) #('Alabama', None, '[edit]')
```

In your original expression you didn't use the optional indicator. To make the group optional you put the `?` at the end, after the closing `)`. The `?:` notation you used means the following group will be ignored **in the result**, but will be always taken into consideration for matching. It basically says: "Match this group, but i don't want to know anything about it in the result"

I think what you wanted after all is this:

`a = re.search('(\w+)(?:\([\w+\s*]+\))?(\[.*\])',string).groups()`

so:

```
import re
s1 = 'Alabama[edit]'
s2 = 'Alabama(test)[edit]'
print(re.search(r'(\w+)(?:\(([\w+\s*]+)\))?(\[.*\])',s1).groups())
#('Alabama', None, '[edit]')
print(re.search(r'(\w+)(?:\(([\w+\s*]+)\))?(\[.*\])',s2).groups())
#('Alabama', 'test', '[edit]')
```

Comment: thank you! looks like it works this way. I have made my  questions more clear in the post , and I am not sure why the optional group in my code doesn't work.....

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much K. Kirsz! I think I get confused about None Capturing Group and optional Group!